# keep increasing the value of a variable in a function the more i call it

Tags: python, function, int, increment, addition

- The first function simply takes a value (let's say 3)
- The second function asks the user if they want to repeat the operation
- If the user agrees to perform the operation again, and this time they enter 2

How can I make the final value of the variable be the addition of the two user inputs?

```
def value():
    amt = int(input("enter value: "))

def go_again():
    again = input("DO you want to go again(y/n)")
    if again == "y":
        value()
    else:
        exit()

value()
again()
```

(This is a shorter code but similar to what I am working on.)

Comment: `value` should, at least, *return* the value that is input, so that it can be used by whoever calls `value`.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically?

Comment: @AMC i just wanted to keep adding the user input till they exit the code

Comment: That's the goal, not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just embed `value` function in `go_again` and run it in `while` loop:

```py
def value():
    return int(input("enter value: "))

def go_again():
    val = value()
    while input("DO you want to go again(y/n)") == "y":
        val += value()
    exit()


go_again()
```